# Login Authentication with parallel Spring security application (Refer details)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm working on a spring boot system where I need to create a microservice for Login and session management. Login/AUtherization request from different microservices will be handled by this service.

One of such microservice is Web application. Now, how should I delegate the request of Login to the Login microservice? [Please refer to image for better understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zs1X.png)

Comment: Do you mean [SSO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on) ?

Comment: @chaoluo Yes. SSO but I'm not sure it is exactly the same thing!